Lebesgue Integral Question
Let $f : [0,1] \to (0, \infty)$ be such that $\int_{E}fdm \leq \sqrt{m(E)}$ for all $E  \subseteq [0,1]$. How might one go about proving that for all $p \in (1,2)$ we have that $\int_{[0,1]}f^p\space dm$ is integrable.
I have attempted to prove the statement by showing that it must be true if f is an indicator function, and then a simple function, but I cannot generalize this to the case of f being a general integrable function. I cannot figure out how to show that there is an upper bound on the integral of simple functions which increase pointwise to such an f. Any advice on how to do so, or perhaps more advantageous approaches would be appreciated. I would also appreciate advice on how to use the fact that $\int_{E}fdm \leq \sqrt{m(E)}$.

$tm(\{f>t\})\le\int_{\{f>t\}} fdm\le \sqrt {(m(\{f>t\}))}$ so $m(\{f>t\})\le\frac 1  {t^{2}}$. A standard result in Measure Theory (based on Fubini's Theorem)  says $\int f^{p}dm=\int_0^{\infty} pt^{p-1}m(\{f>t\}) dt$. Split this integral into the integral form $0$ to $1$ and the integral form $1$ to $\infty$. For the first integral use the fact that $m(\{f>t\}) \leq 1$. For the second integral use the fact that $m(\{f>t\})\le\frac 1  {t^{2}}$. Rest should be easy.
